# Java I get an error but it still runs

Tags: java

I get this error when I run this code and don't type a integer, but it still prints "Please type a integer"  This thing is really annoying me first I had to indent every line of code even though my indent button didn't work so I had to press space four times on every code.  Now its asking me to add more details so here ya go...

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at Testing2.main(Testing2.java:22)
```

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Testing2 {
    static Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int RandomNum = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

        System.out.println("Your random number is out of 100 is " + RandomNum + "!");
        System.out.println("Please type another number");

        if (!userInput.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Enter an integer");
        }
        int numberEntered = userInput.nextInt();
        int Numbered = RandomNum*numberEntered;
        System.out.println(RandomNum + "*" + numberEntered + "=" + Numbered);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you see any purpose with your `if`? Even if the `if` condition resolves to false, you're still trying to read the next int.

Comment: If the input is done via separate lines, you'll have to deal with the newlines. You're often better to read the whole line via `nextLine()` and parse the String for an int.

Comment: Removing the if condition makes it not work.

Comment: Your brackets are definitely wacky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sotirious Delimanolis said I dont see any purpose of your if.

Other than that your code is pretty straight-forward. I still don't quite understand your question. But if you are wondering to remove the Exception its simple that you need to ensure that the input you enter is of integer type.

InputMismatchException is thrown by a Scanner to indicate that the token retrieved does not match the pattern for the expected type, or that the token is out of range for the expected type.

Usually methods like nextInt() and hasNextInt() first skips any input that matches the delimiter pattern, and then attempt to return the next token.

Hence make sure either you handle that exception or try to parse a string and then change it to an integer or follow Bohemian's comment to extract the values.

Hope this help you get a better clarity.